# Loading bar inside Jquery keep moving after 100%

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to start loading bar on page 4, but it keeps going beyond 100% messing with the layout. If I take the bar loading function away on page 1, it works fine. Maybe I need to close that animation function somehow?

http://jsfiddle.net/reizer/9w6vu7f1/

```js
$('#cnt2, #cnt3, #cnt4, #cnt5').hide();
$('.button').click(function() {
//code
var curr = $(".question:visible");
var next = curr.next(".question");
next.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
curr.fadeOut(300);
if (!next.next(".question").length) {
  //Begin Bar Transition
  $(".button").hide(function() {
    $("#bar").width(0);
    $("#bar").delay(500).animate({
      width: '+=50%'
    }, 'slow').delay(600).animate({
      width: '+=20%'
    }, 'slow').delay(60).animate({
      width: '+=10%'
    }).delay(2000).animate({
      width: '+=20%'
    }, 'slow');
  });
}
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    background-color: #333;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #666;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.question {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#row {
    display: table-row;
}
.button {
    background: rgba(148, 190, 22, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#94be16', endColorstr='#769d00', GradientType=0);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #FFF;
}
.button:focus, .button:hover {
    background: rgba(168, 216, 22, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a8d816', endColorstr='#82ad00', GradientType=0);
}
.last {
    border-color:#666;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0 0 0 1px
}
#bar {
    background-color: #3C0;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="cnt" class="question">this is content of page 1
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="cnt2" class="question">this is content of page 2</div>
  <div id="cnt3" class="question">this is content of page 3</div>
  <div id="cnt4" class="question">this is content of page 4
    <br>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="table">
    <div id="row">
      <div class="button">CLICK HERE</div>
      <div class="button last">CLICK HERE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$(".button")` has more than 1 match the callback passed to `$('.button').hide();`  will run multiple times, extending the bar beyond `100%`

Simply moving the code for extending progress bar outside the callback will solve the issue:

```js
$('#cnt2, #cnt3, #cnt4, #cnt5').hide();
$('.button').click(function() {
  //code
  var curr = $(".question:visible");
  var next = curr.next(".question");
  next.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
  curr.fadeOut(300);
  if (!next.next(".question").length) {
    //Begin Bar Transition
    $('.button').hide();
    $("#bar").width(0);
    $("#bar").delay(500).animate({
      width: '+=50%'
    }, 'slow').delay(600).animate({
      width: '+=20%'
    }, 'slow').delay(60).animate({
      width: '+=10%'
    }).delay(2000).animate({
      width: '+=20%'
    }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: #666;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.question {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
#table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#row {
  display: table-row;
}
.button {
  background: rgba(148, 190, 22, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(148, 190, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 157, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#94be16', endColorstr='#769d00', GradientType=0);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
}
.button:focus,
.button:hover {
  background: rgba(168, 216, 22, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(168, 216, 22, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 173, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a8d816', endColorstr='#82ad00', GradientType=0);
}
.last {
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px
}
#bar {
  background-color: #3C0;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="cnt" class="question">this is content of page 1
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="cnt2" class="question">this is content of page 2</div>
  <div id="cnt3" class="question">this is content of page 3</div>
  <div id="cnt4" class="question">this is content of page 4
    <br>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="table">
    <div id="row">
      <div class="button">CLICK HERE</div>
      <div class="button last">CLICK HERE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx for the answer. But if i take that bar code out of the function, i have no issues even though there are few buttons on a page instead of one:
http://jsfiddle.net/reizer/atbkvtsb/

Comment: @reizer I didn't get your comment... you meant to say the issue is solved or this creates some other issues..?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the fiddle. The issue is pretty much resolved, but on the last page I would like to eliminate the buttons instead of being left with one. I'm not fast with jquery i'm playing around with your code to match what i'm trying to do.

Comment: ohh boy, I'm not sure why in your code here 2 buttons turn into 1 on last page, but i just copied your code and it solved the issue perfectly. Thank You very much!!